# How do I declare a variable in the shell, read input from the user and output the result?

Tags: shell, unix, arguments

I am new to the UNIX world.  Our teacher makes us learn everything ourself and I must of missed something in class.  I only know C# and am used to textboxes.  I have a file named `likes` and the following is displayed when I cat it:

```
dave,coors
mike,bud
linda,coors
gary,miller
mike,miller
sally,coors
dave,bud
sally,miller
```

I have created a file in bin named `drinks`. I need the following to be my output when executing `drinks`.

```
$ drinks dave
dave likes to drink:

coors
bud

total number of beers dave likes to drink: 2
```

If I run `drinks sally` the output needs to match sallys likes.

How do I declare a variable that will make the input of the name on the shell when executing the file to the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the arguments to a shell script through the variables `$1` (first arg), `$2` (second arg), ..., `${42}` (fourtysecond arg).

Within your `drinks` script you can reference the name with `$1`.

```
#!/bin/sh
if test $# = 0; then
    # User forgot to provide a name.
    printf '%s\n' "usage: $0 name" >&2
    exit 1
fi
printf '%s\n' "$1 likes to drink"
# Rest of code left as an exercise.
```

Comment: Do I have to declare variables for each name or can I make one variable that reads "name" after the drinks execution?

Comment: if so what keyword do I us to read it, is it read?

Comment: No need to declare shell variables. Just assign, e.g. `name=$1` and then use `$name`. If you want to read into a variable from stdin, use `echo Please enter the name` followed by `read name`.

Comment: Thank you much! thats all i need...now i can grep and awk

Comment: Ok, the next thing would be to upvote and accept this answer if your reputation allows.

Comment: It wont let me upvote because I dont have 15 reputation yet